# What is a good quick pathfinding algorithm?

Tags: language-agnostic, path-finding, flood-fill

What is a good path finding algorithm when you care the amount of time it takes but not how long the path is.

Also is there a faster algorithm if you don't care about the path at all but just want to check reachability.

(Is Flood Fill a good algorithm for this sort of stuff?)

Comment: I'm thinking of a 2d square grid

Comment: Just letting you know, the industry standard for efficiency and reliability is [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*)

Answer (score 3):

What kind of graph are you finding a path on? Is it a grid? Is it a weight graph?

These things all matter.

Some algorithms that may be helpful include

- Breadth First Search
- Depth First Search
- Dijkstra's Algorithm
- A* (A Star)
- Floyd Warshall's Algorithm
- The Bellman Ford Algorithm

Comment: Depending on how many possible states and possible paths exist in your problem, you might consider a variant on A* using a bloom filter (instead of a set) to record previously observed states.  This worked well for me in a couple toy tests. FWIW, I called this A^.